# How does the Merkle proof mechanism exactly work in Ethereum? This is straightforward in bitcoin but

Tags: spv, proof, merkle

I've searched this site and elsewhere but can't find anywhere this is explained.

In bitcoin, it's straightforward. If you're a light client (SPV) in bitcoin, I understand how with the regular Merkle Tree there you simply concatenate the hashes and rehash them upward in the path toward the root USING with the Merkle Proof provided by the full node in order to verify data integrity.

But how is this done in Ethereum? Because from what I understand about the Merkle Patricie Trie, it's different from the Merkle Tree in that you can't construct/calculate it by concatenating hashes and rehashing them along the path toward the root hash. What exactly is the process used here to calculate the hashes upward eventually leading to the calculation of the root hash? I suppose, in other words, how does the Merkle proof look format-wise?

I'm not trying to program anything by the way. Just trying to understand conceptually.